# splashscreen is not displaying

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

can anyone please tell me how to create Splashscreen ??I am using jdeveloper 11.1.2.4.0 and cordova 2.2..
I have followed every steps mentioned in phonegap documentation..But still I am not able to create splashscreen..

Here is my class extending DroidGap

```
package mobile;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import oracle.adfmf.amx.event.ActionEvent;
import oracle.adfmf.framework.api.AdfmfContainerUtilities;


public class splashClass extends DroidGap
{
    public splashClass() {
        super();
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);     
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash); 
        this.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 120000);
        super.loadUrl("file:///assets/www/index.html",120000); 
      }   

}
```

R.drawable.splash is showing an error as "type or field 'splash' is not found in drawable" when I have added splash.png file into drawable..

But when I took a previouslly added image from drawable like "R.drawable.ic_delete",the same is not displaying on emulator..only black screen is coming..

Thnks..

Comment: did u really put "splash" in drawable folder

Comment: where is setcontentview() of your activity within oncreate()?

Comment: @sam -yes..I have added "splash" in drawable folder..

Comment: @Sharad - can you please tell me what does setcontentview() really do?

Comment: its a layout for your activity.if you remove it then u cant see any Graphical user interface for your activity

Comment: just use imageview in your layout file then assign splash drawable to it.then use handler to show splash for certain period of time.

Comment: @user2447044  http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/. Don't use splash screen if it does nothing except delaying